# NoClassDefFoundError with Spring 3.1 Controller Unit Test

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, junit4, noclassdeffounderror

I have a simple `autowired` Controller and a test. When the project is built with mvn and code coverage goals emma:emma and emma:check, the test case fails with following error.

Simple "mvn test" command succeeds.
"mvn test emma:emma emma:check" fails.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebDataBinderFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using cobertura, add this to your report section:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <check>
                <lineRate>120</lineRate>
              </check>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

then do:

```
mvn site
```

then open in browser:

```
target/site/index.html
```

You will see the cobertura report there.
Best to add these kind of plugins to your parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dependency of spring-web in test. If not, then try adding dependency on `org.springframework:spring-web`